# Allowed memory size X exhausted (tried to allocate Y), where Y < X

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this error when I try to edit a specific WordPress page:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1265664 bytes) in /directory-of-site/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889

Two things have surprised me:

1. The amount of memory allocated is smaller than the allowed memory, reason I don't understand this error;
2. the amount of memory I'm allowed on this server is 640Mb, so I've tried to define the variables `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` and `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` to 600M and I still have the same error.
3. The error comes from a core file of WordPress which is: wp-includes/wp-db.php

I have tried to specify the memory limit in the `.htaccess`, in the `php.ini`, in the `wp-config.php` file using `init_set()` and other various idea I've found here and on other forums/websites and the problem persists.

I've also tried the usual disabling of modules or theme and I still have the same error, but only on one specific page which is the homepage. I can still edit it using Visual Composer.

Do any of you have an idea what I can change to have this working again?

### [UPDATE 2018-06-20 16:20]

After the first questions, lets make this maybe a little more specific, I'm loading the WordPress Admin edition page for my homepage (URL: `/wp-admin/post.php?post=25&action=edit`), not the homepage it self.

The error logs I've found are the following (WordPress debug.log):

```
[20-Jun-2018 14:15:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/wordpress-directory/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php7.1/lib/php') in /wordpress-directory/wp-settings.php on line 84
[20-Jun-2018 14:18:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1638400 bytes) in /wordpress-directory/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889
[20-Jun-2018 14:18:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1888256 bytes) in /wordpress-directory/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889
```

So I've disabled cache as to see if that could be the problem, but I'm still having errors.

The error logs I've found are the following (PHP error.log):

```
[Wed Jun 20 16:09:32.850690 2018] [:error] [pid 5855:tid 140131419744000] [client 213.3.54.242:56174] FastCGI: server "/.config/apache/websiteURL/.fpm/php5.external" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 671088640 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1265664 bytes) in /wordpress-directory/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889, referer: https://websiteURL/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

The WordPress I'm using is up-to-date as are all the plug-ins installed. Can I find what else uses up memory? This is a hosted server with different dev sites, eventually I could try to empty it up a bit of older sites which have been migrated to see if it helps.

Comment: what on earth is your homepage doing that it uses 670MB of memory? have you checked your `error_log`?

Comment: That's the amount it tried to allocate at that time, not including the amount already allocated.  You have a very bad memory leak somewhere if your site is trying to allocate over 640MB on a single request.

Comment: Just because you are only requesting 1,265,664 bytes of 671,088,640 bytes doesn't mean that there is 1,265,664 bytes **still available**. Something may have already exhausted most of the available memory.

Comment: @Devon: fully agree, how could I find where this is coming from? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the purpose of a profiler.  Other than that, you'd have to do trial and error by disabling plugins or removing code.  You probably have a faulty loop somewhere.

Comment: @Devon: any profiler module to suggest on WordPress which could help me out here? I'm surprised of having this error on a WordPress site, this is the very first time and I have tried to remove all Modules and use the default theme and I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally duplicated the page and had everything back on track that way. Apparently There must have been a bug on the specific page. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

set memory limit to -1 in your php code. it will work

Comment: what type of data are you loading in the page?